# boolean condition inside for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

I'm trying to understand what is the "flag = false" / "flag == false" meaning inside the for loop..

```
    if(flag){
    for (let index = 0, flag = false; index < myArr.length, flag == false; index++) {
        if(myArr[index].show == 1){
            flag = true;
            setFullMessage(index)
        }
    }}
```

tnx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple conditions in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546312/multiple-conditions-in-for-loop)

Comment: no it doesn't..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN | for - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) (*emphasize mine*):

> The for statement creates a loop that consists of **three optional expressions**, enclosed in parentheses and separated by semicolons, followed by a statement (usually a block statement) to be executed in the loop.

and [MDN | Comma operator (,) - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) (*emphasis mine*):

> The comma operator (,) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand. This lets you create a **compound expression** in which multiple expressions are evaluated, with the compound expression's final value being the value of the rightmost of its member expressions. This is commonly used to provide multiple parameters to a for loop.

So `for (let index = 0, flag = false; index < myArr.length, flag == false; index++) {}`
has three expressions

- *initialization*: `let index = 0, flag = false`
- *condition*: `index < myArr.length, flag == false`
- *final-expression*: `index++`

The initialization expression init the running variable `index` and sets the `flag` to `false`. This is at the start of the `for` loop.

The condition checks for the `index` is at the end of `myArr`, then checks the `flag` for being `false` and then sets the value of the last expression (`false`) to be the value of the whole condition. This will stop the loop, if flag is true.

There is an issue with that, because it won't stop at the end off `myArr`, if none of the `myArr` elements has a `show` value of `1`

```js
myArr = [
  {show: 0},
  {show: 0},
  {show: 0},
];
flag = true;
if (flag) {
  for (let index = 0, flag = false; index < myArr.length, flag == false; index++) {
    if (myArr[index].show == 1) {
      flag = true;
    }
    console.log(myArr[index], index, flag)
  }
}
```

The condition should better be `index < myArr.length && flag == false`

```js
myArr = [
  {show: 0},
  {show: 0},
  {show: 0},
];
flag = true;
if (flag) {
  for (let index = 0, flag = false; index < myArr.length && flag == false; index++) {
    if (myArr[index].show == 1) {
      flag = true;
    }
    console.log(myArr[index], index, flag)
  }
}
```