# How to write simple "number stairs" with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

i have to write simple code with JS and HTML obviously. It has to ask for min and max number using prompt, and write stairs from min to max. For example, for min 2 and max 6 the result will be:

```
2
 3
  4
   5
    6
```

I solved it by adding spaces from left margin, but my code doesn't work. Please help me with optimizing and making code work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Stairs generator</h2>

<button onclick="stairs()">Start</button>

<script>
     
     function stairs() {
     var max;
     var min;
     var space = '&nbsp;'
     var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Enter first number"));
        
        while(num1==null  isNaN(num2))
        {
            num1 = prompt("Enter first number")
        } 
        var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Enter first number"));
        while(num2==null  isNaN(num2))
        {
            num2 = prompt("Enter second number")
        }
        if (num1 > num2) 
        {
            max = num1;
            min = num2;
        }
        else if (num1 < num2)
        {
            max = num2;
            min = num1;
        }
        else 
        {
            document.write(space = space + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')
            document.write(num1 + '<br/>')
        }
        document.write('<p>');
        while(min <= max) 
        {
            document.write(space = space + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')
            document.write(min + '<br/>')
            min++
        }
        document.write('</p>')
        }
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `while` loop conditions are incorrect: check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while

Comment: This will help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546312/multiple-conditions-in-for-loop

Answer (score 1):

first of all the numbers wont be perfect stairs unless you use monospace fonts aka fonts that has all the same sized letters/numbers

second use a while loop

```
var NumHolder;
var timesLooped = 0;
while(num1-1 < num2){
   num1;
   document.write += num1;
   document.write += '<br>'
   for(x = 0;x-1 < timesLooped;x++){
      document.write += '&nbsp;'
   }
   num1 ++;//adds 1 to var
}
```

so it will loop until num1-1 is equals to num2 
ex:
promts are 1 & 4
it loops 1 displays then 2 displays then 3 then 4
output : 
1
 2
  3
   4

Answer (score 0):

You had some syntax errors in you javascript code ( you forgot the OR operator in the while loops) and in the first while loop you asked isNUll(num2) thisch was always true

```js
     function stairs() {
     var max;
     var min;
     var space = '&nbsp;'
     var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Enter first number"));
        
        while(num1==null || isNaN(num1))
        {
            num1 = prompt("Enter first number")
        } 
        var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Enter first number"));
        while(num2==null || isNaN(num2))
        {
            num2 = prompt("Enter second number")
        }
        if (num1 > num2) 
        {
            max = num1;
            min = num2;
        }
        else if (num1 < num2)
        {
            max = num2;
            min = num1;
        }
        else 
        {
            document.write(space = space + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')
            document.write(num1 + '<br/>')
        }
        document.write('<p>');
        while(min <= max) 
        {
            document.write(space = space + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')
            document.write(min + '<br/>')
            min++
        }
        document.write('</p>')
        }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Stairs generator</h2>

<button onclick="stairs()">Start</button>

</body>
</html>
```